# System.Windows.Shapes.Path stroke

Tags: c#, xaml

I need get border this kind (only red line). I need to get the full left side and two sides half. Grey sides only for example.

[image]

Now I have next code:

```
var f = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
f.Height = 40;
f.Width = 60;
f.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
f.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

How can I do it?

I can use only System.Windows.Shapes.Path and only c# code. I don't modify xaml page.

For example i have this rectangle.

[image]

If I reduce the upper line then the inner part (filling) reduce too.

Code this rectangle in [svg editor](http://editor.method.ac/) (View -> Source...):

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
     <g>
      <title>background</title>
      <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
      <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
       <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
      </g>
     </g>
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <path id="svg_1" d="m227.92666,205.89499l-212.49917,0l0,-184l255.00001,0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#CFCA6D"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you planning to put this border around?
Is there a reason why you only want half a border?

Comment: @DanielleSummers not necessarily 50%. The main task is to obtain only a part of the upper and lower sides. However, there should also be no right-hand side.